# Video JS-- How do I remove the playback controls?

Tags: php, web-services, html5-video, video.js

I am using VideoJS to play videos on my page, how do I remove the playback controls?

I want to auto play once the page is loaded without controls, once the playback is done I want to trigger a webservice.

any ideas on how to do this?

Michael

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"  poster="images/loader.gif" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="test.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
<source src="test.webm" type='video/webm'>
<p class="vjs-no-js">
  To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
  <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
</p>
  </video>
```

http://videojs.com/

Answer (score 0):

write this attribute , i think your problem will be solve

```
<video autoplay ...>
```

Comment: Hi, this starts the video, but I want to remove the Pause button and timeline, i want to ensure the video is played to the end without interuptions.